# Button make my app crashes?

Tags: c#, xaml, button, xamarin, cross-platform

i'am trying to make a button that's make me go to another page. but every time i pess the button my app crashes D: looking for help!

My Code.

Page 1 named "LoginPage"

```
public LoginPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Signup());
}

async void SignupProcedure(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new Signup());
}

<Button x:Name="Btn_Signup" Text="Sign up" Clicked="SignupProcedure"/>
```

Page 2 Named "Signup"

```
async void OnPreviousPageButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   await Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPage());
}
```

Comment: If you app crashes, please provide the stack trace and exception that produces. If it doesn't add a try/catch around your contents in your button handlers and check if they throw an exception.

Comment: Define what you mean by *crash*? Do you get an exception? If so add it to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure your MainPage is declared in App.xaml.cs and not the constructor of your LoginPage like in your example.

Like the following:

```
public App()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Signup());

    }
```

Comment: I dont know what it did, but i helped. Ty so much :D

Comment: The constructor of the App is what sets up your application. You need to set your first page there because without it, the App doesn't know to start at your LoginPage and it will not see where you set your MainPage.